# Substr string function

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to get the string of 35 characters from starting but every word should not split.e.g.

```
select SUBSTR('monika awasthi awasthi awasthi awasthi',1,35) from dual

output is :monika awasthi awasthi awasthi awas
```

but if my string end is in the middle of the word then output should be print till last space:e.g

**Desired output:**

```
monika awasthi awasthi awasthi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need substr + [instr](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/INSTR.html) with negative 3rd parameter: from the doc by this link:

> If position is negative, then Oracle counts backward from the end of
> string and then searches backward from the resulting position.

So it would be simple

```
substr(str, 1, instr(str,' ', (35 - length(str))))
```

Another approach is to use regexp_substr:
`regexp_substr('monika awasthi awasthi awasthi awasthi', '^.{1,35}\s')`

Full example:

```sql
select
    str
   ,substr(str, 1, instr(str,' ', (35 - length(str)))) substring
   ,regexp_substr('monika awasthi awasthi awasthi awasthi', '^.{1,35}\s') substring2
from (select 'monika awasthi awasthi awasthi awasthi' str from dual);
```

Results:

```sql
STR                                    SUBSTRING                           SUBSTRING2
-------------------------------------- ----------------------------------- -------------------------------
monika awasthi awasthi awasthi awasthi monika awasthi awasthi awasthi      monika awasthi awasthi awasthi
```

Answer (score 0):

Just expand the substr from 35 to a larger length. For instance:

```
    SUBSTR('string',1,100)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be simpler expressed with a regex:

```
regexp_substr('monika awasthi awasthi awasthi awasthi', '^.{1,35}(\s|$)')
```

`^.{1,35}(\s|$)` means: maximum 35 characters from the start of the string, ending with a space or the end of string.

You can `rtrim()` the result is you want to get rid of the potentially trailing space.

Comment: using above regexp output will be (monika awasthi awasthi awasthi awasthi)  which  exceeds  35 characters .

Comment: I want max 35 characters in string & in case of word  spliting it will print the string till last space from 35th character

Comment: regular expression should be `'^.{1,35}\s'`

Comment: @SayanMalakshinov: quite, yes. We just need to manage the possibility that the string has less than 35 characters, so ` '^.{1,35}(\s|$)'`.

Comment: @GMB I'd avoid using regex functions in such cases using `case when length(str)<=35 then str else regexp_substr...`. Regex functions are too slow

Answer (score 0):

Try this below option-

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=e708a80f3024874c70aa4cec71a6d9d3)

```
select 
case 
    when INSTR(str,' ',35) = 0 then str
    else SUBSTR(str, 1, INSTR(str,' ',35))
end
from cte
```